a4 size div scrolling top issue based on scale value
i using a div with a4-size dimensions , i need a4 div vertically and horizontally on center of page , if scale value is less it is working fine , but if scale value is more than one i am unable to scroll to the top , and text inside a4 div is not visible , can any please give the solution
Thanks in advance


  let scale = 1;

  function zoomIn() {
    scale += 0.1;
    updateZoom();
  }

  function zoomOut() {
    if (scale > 0.2) { // Limiting minimum zoom level
      scale -= 0.1;
      updateZoom();
    }
  }

  function updateZoom() {
    document.getElementById("a4Div").style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
    document.getElementById("letterContent").style.fontSize = (100 / scale) + "%";
  }
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }
  
  #a4Div {
    width: 210mm; /* A4 paper width */
    height: 297mm; /* A4 paper height */
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; /* Ensures content stays within A4 div */
  }
  
  #letterContent {
    padding: 20px;
    transform-origin: top left; /* Adjust scaling from top-left corner */
  }
  
  #zoomControls {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }
<div id="a4Div">
  <div id="letterContent">
    <h1>Zoomable A4 Letter</h1>
    <p>This is a sample letter content. You can zoom in and zoom out using the buttons below.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="zoomControls">
    <button onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
    <button onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>
  </div>
</div>




I have update your body and letterContent css classes
in updateZoom function you need to center the position


let scale = 1;

  function zoomIn() {
    scale += 0.1;
    updateZoom();
  }

  function zoomOut() {
    if (scale > 0.2) { // Limiting minimum zoom level
      scale -= 0.1;
      updateZoom();
    }
  }

  function updateZoom() {
  const a4Div = document.getElementById("a4Div");
  a4Div.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
  a4Div.style.transformOrigin = 'center center';

  a4Div.style.left = `calc(50% - ${(210 * scale) / 2}mm)`;
  a4Div.style.top = `calc(50% - ${(297 * scale) / 2}mm)`;

  document.getElementById("letterContent").style.fontSize = `${100 / scale}%`;
}
body {
 overflow: auto; 

  }
  
  #a4Div {
    width: 210mm; /* A4 paper width */
    height: 297mm; /* A4 paper height */
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; /* Ensures content stays within A4 div */
  }
  
  #letterContent {
  padding: 20px;
  transform-origin: center center; 
}
  
  #zoomControls {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }
<div id="a4Div">
  <div id="letterContent">
    <h1>Zoomable A4 Letter</h1>
    <p>This is a sample letter content. You can zoom in and zoom out using the buttons below.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="zoomControls">
    <button onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
    <button onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>
  </div>
</div>



